# Flex Barcode Component for Barcode EAN 128 with Application Identifiers

Tags: apache-flex, components, gs1-128

I am looking for a flex component to generate a barcode similar to the one below.

See Image http://img.skitch.com/20100716-g4456feuw8af1b1q6i1p2kj3tt.jpg

I have found a similar plugin, at flex2.bsi-scs.com/BarCodeDemo/index.php. But could not replicate the Application Identifiers by just using the "( )"

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use zxing library available on google code :

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

EAN-8 and EAN-13 are supported

You will find in the source code an example on how to use the library